# SQL Server: How to get the extra records comparing 2 tables along with another column which should not be compared

Tags: sql-server-2014

Here is the Sample Data I Have

```
INSERT INTO MA_NewRevised VALUES 
       ('Vishal','SD','Col',2),
        ('Shivu','SD','Col',3),
        ('Pavithra','SD','Col',4),
        ('Keerthi','SD','Col',5),
        ('Bharath','SD','Col',6),
        ('Radhu','SD','Col',2),
        ('Vanitha','SD','Col',3),
        ('Anirudh','SD','Col',4),
        ('Amit','SD','Col',5)

         INSERT INTO MA_OldValues VALUES 
       ('Vishal','SD','Col',2),
        ('Shivu','SD','Col',3),
        ('Pavithra','SD','Col',2),
        ('Keerthi','SD','Col',3),
        ('Bharath','SD','Col',6),
        ('Radhu','SD','Col',2),
        ('Vanitha','SD','Col',3),
        ('Raju','SD','Col',1)
```

**First Code:**

```
SELECT * FROM MA_NewRevised n
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM MA_OldValues o
```

The above code will give me.

[image: Except Values]

**Second Code**

```
SELECT Name,Groups,CommonColumn FROM MA_NewRevised 
        EXCEPT
        SELECT Name,Groups,CommonColumn FROM MA_OldValues
```

The Above Code will give me:

[image: Except without Quantity]

***But the required Output is***

[image: Except without Quantity, but output with Qty]

That is, Distinct values with respect to Name, Groups, CommonColumn should be Selected along with the quantity of the new Revised table(First Table)

Answer (score 0):

To your query, which does not return the extra column, but return correct rows, join the original table and retrieve the value of the extra column. Since there is no unique field in your data, you may have to join on all fields.

```
;with cte as (
SELECT Name,Groups,CommonColumn FROM MA_NewRevised 
EXCEPT
SELECT Name,Groups,CommonColumn FROM MA_OldValues
)
select cte.*, n.Quatity -- or n.Quantity, not sure which is the correct name of your column
from cte
inner join MA_NewRevised n on cte.Name = n.Name and cte.Groups = n.Groups and cte.CommonColumn = n.CommonColumn
```